# Adding Commands to the TexMaker Quick Start Wizard

Tags: texmaker

Like most people, I have a set of commands that I define and packages I include at the top of almost every document I write. TexMaker's QS wizard is very nice to just click a few checkboxes and get some of the packages, but only has a the ones I use most in those. Is there a way to program the wizard (or another wizard) that will add in my common commands and packages automatically?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it.